# Move status bar on watch face using more than setStatusBarGravity

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have this kind of problem (also can be seen on picture below)

I am trying to create my own watch face, however, I am struggling with moving the status bar icons slightly so it does not collide with the background.

Current setup on initiating setWatchFaceStyle is as follows

```
.setStatusBarGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
```

Any ideas how to move it a little below or do I have to adjust the watch background?

Here is the screenshot.

[image: Status bar coliding with watchface background]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the static variables of the Gravity-Class you can use your own settings. Just like:

```
setStatusBarGravity(Gravity.CENTER | 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no possiblility to adjust the position more exactly than the Gravity.XXX directions.

Even in the [design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/wear/watchfaces.html) they are speaking about "several fixed locations" on the wearable.